# How can I do one-sided Grubb's test for outlier in R as in Minitab?

Tags: r

In minitab we can do grubbs test with three options:
1.Smallest or largest data value is an outlier
2.Smallest data value is an outlier
3.Largest data value is an outlier

I am doing it in R now. Here is the code for tow-sided test.

```
library(outliers)   。
x=rnorm(30) 
x[21]=10 
grubbs = grubbs.test(x, type = 10, opposite = FALSE, two.sided = TRUE)
```

If I set 'two.sided=FALSE', R gives me either lowest or largerst value as an outlier.

```
grubbs = grubbs.test(x, type = 10, opposite = FALSE, two.sided = FALSE)
```

Is there a way that I can set as minitab does? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself:

1. for minitab (1.Smallest or largest data value is an outlier):
   **two.sided = TRUE**

2） for minitab (3.Largest data value is an outlier):
**two.sided = FALSE**
Because by default, the test is performed on the highest value .

3. for minitab(2.Smallest data value is an outlier )

If you want to do the test for the lowest value, use **two.sided = FALSE**, and simply add the argument **opposite = TRUE**: